# Why is this Syntax valid in C#?

Tags: c#

In a WPF project I got I have a class called IHavePassword and in another file a listener for a button like this

```
private void DoLogin(object parameter)
{
    if (parameter is IHavePassword passwordContainer)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

My question relates to the if statement after the "is" keyword, what is it doing there? Is it comparing the method parameter to an "IHavePassword" class new instance?

Comment: That's [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching).

Comment: because language spec says so :) It checks whether parameter is an instance of a type which implements `IHavePassword` and provides `passwordContainer` variable of type `IHavePassword` if it is.

Answer (score 6):

Great question you have asked, in C# there is a concept called pattern matching. so the primary Author is trying to check if parameter coming is compatible with IHavePassord. if this is compatible the variable then becomes passwordContainer.

This link to microsoft documentation will help.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is

```
private void DoLogin(object parameter)
{
// expr (parameter) is type(IHavePassword) varname (passwordContainer)
    if (parameter is IHavePassword passwordContainer)
    {
        // if true you can now have access to passwordContainer.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

What this does, is to let you check if the object is of type IHavePassword and if it is, you can use it afterwards by using the variable passwordContianer.

This is called pattern matching, which you can learn more about here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is

Answer (score 4):

This is called "Pattern Matching". It was added in C# 7.0.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#the-is-type-pattern-expression

From the article:

> the `is` expression both tests the variable and assigns it to a new variable of the proper type

So in your question, the variable `passwordContainer` is the variable declaration set aside for the `is` being `true`.

Answer (score 2):

this should help

```
private void Simple(object parameter)
{
    if (parameter is int)
    {
        //do something which does not need the type
        Something();

        //this line will not work as it does number not exist, see below SimpleOther
        //var newTotal = 1 + number;


         //this line does not work as object is not a int
        //var newTotal = 1 + parameter;
    }
}

private void SimpleOther(object parameter)
{
    if (parameter is int number)
    {
        //this works as it know its type is int and 1 is an int.
        var newTotal = 1 + number;
    }
}

private void CommonNormalUsage(object parameter)
{
    if (parameter is SomeClass someClass)
    {
        //where SomeClass as a methood called AddSomethingSpecialMethod
        someClass.AddSomethingSpecialMethod();
    }

    //this is done so the runtime knows what type parameter is and con only work 
    //with an instance which has been "cast" to that type
}
```